# Issue with russian-letter links in Aspose pdf-viewer

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, aspose

I am faced with an encoding problem while using embedded `aspose pdf-previewer` and `doc-to-pdf` converter in my java project.

When I try to convert a `.doc` file with clickable links that contain Russian symbols to a pdf file using the `com.aspose.words.Document.saveToPdf(...)` method I get a good pdf file. But when I try to open this file in standard `aspose pdf-previewer` and follow these links with Russian symbols I see a "wrong url" error.

Links by itself looks okay (Russian letters look correct) but in mouseover tooltip I note a wrong encoded symbols instead of Russian ones.

How can I deal with this problem? 
Should I convert doc file with some specific options or maybe should to configure the pdf-previewer in another way?

Answer (score 1):

Document.saveToPdf() method is [no longer available in the latest library](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Migrate+to+Aspose.Words+9.2+or+Higher), you can just use Document.save("filename.ext") method to save to pdf or any other supported format.

Try the latest version, chances are that this bug might already be fixed. As, I tried to convert a Word document to Pdf with Russian letters in link, the encoding seems to work fine.

I work as a Developer Evangelist for Aspose.